# Display data in view from database Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So i have two tables:

**orders**

id | time | meals_id | vege

1  | 12:00 | 1        |       0

**ingredients**

id | value | meals_id

1  | cheese| 1

2  | beef  | 1

where ingredients id is type of ingredients like meat.
I'd like to display data in my order view, but I have no idea how show value of ingredients.

This is my order model

```
public function ingredients(){
return $this->hasMany(ingredient::class);
}
```

ingredient model

```
public function order(){
return $this->hasMany(order::class);
}
```

and orderController

```
public function show(){
$orders = order::where('vege', 0)->get();
return view('home', ['orders' => $orders]);
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

in order model make a relation with ingredients

```
public function ingredients()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'order_id' ,'id');
}
```

you must have a field in ingredients order_id

then you can get order with ingredients

```
$orders = Orders::with('ingredients')->where('vege',0)->get();

return view('home',compact('orders'));
```

in home view you can easily

```
foreach($orders as $order){
  foreach($order->ingredients as $i){
    echo $i->id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

orderController

```
public function show(){
$orders = order::where('vege', 0)->get();
return view("home",compact('orders'));
}
```

home view

```
  foreach($orders as $order){
  foreach($order->ingredients as $i){
  echo {{ $i->id }};
  }
 }
```